# iframe - can't manage a scrollbar using overflow in CSS file

Tags: css, iframe

I would like to show scrollbar on mobile phones but on bigger screens (for example - on PC) I would like to hide this scrollbar.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="750" src="http://meteo.pl/um/php/meteorogram_id_um.php?ntype=0u&id=661"></iframe>
```

and here is CSS:

```
iframe {
overflow-x: scroll !important;
overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Finally I can see two scrollbars.
When I try in this way:

```
iframe {
overflow-x: hidden!important;
overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

I always get two scrollbars, so I can't manage this scrollbar in CSS file. Why??

Answer (score 1):

1. Set an **id** to the iframe attribute:

`<iframe src="your_source" scrolling="yes" id="myFrame"/>`

2. We need events on which we call functions, so add attributes onload and onresize to

`<body onresize="f()" onload="f()">
...
</body>`

3.Finally add the javascript function that will handle the changes of the scrolling depending on screen size:

```
<script>
function f(){
if(document.body.clientWidth<700)

//condition which checks if the Width of page is less than 700, put your own value here

{document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("scrolling","yes");}

//if yes, than, with help of function .getElementById we fetch element with id="myFrame" and change its attribute’s scrolling value to "yes" (mobile device)

else

{document.getElementById("myFrame").setAttribute("scrolling","no");}

//if the width of the page is not less than 700 (or any),  then scrolling's value is "no" (widescreen resolution)

}
<script>
```

Comment: I can control client width using CSS: `@media screen and (min-width: 1280px)` - and it's all. But it's really impossible to manage scrollbar in css? I need to use javascript?

Comment: It is possible to deal with scrolling using CSS, however you have to enable and disable scrolling depending on screen size, because your users can use both mobile and laptop. To do this, the best way would be to write a javascript function that will be constantly calculating the width of the screen and acting accordingly.

Comment: So if it is possible - show me how I can do it. Forget about "laptops and mobile phones". I would like to know how to manage scrollbar in CSS file.

Comment: In the second case, when you are getting two scrollbars while trying to remove everything, just add `scrolling="no"` within `<iframe>` and then apply `overflow: hidden` inside CSS file. As a result, you will not see any scrolls.